# how to split hours by 30 mins in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
final response = await apiResponseMaker(result, ModelType.working_hour);
      if (response['success']) {
        List<WorkingHourModel> workingHours = response['hours'];

        int startTime = int.parse(workingHours[0].startTime.split(':')[0]);
        int endTime = int.parse(workingHours[0].endTime.split(':')[0]);
        int hoursLeft = endTime - startTime + 1;

        print('Hours-------- $hoursLeft');
        List<String> hours = List.generate(hoursLeft * 2, (i) => '${endTime(i/2).truncate()}:${i%2 == 1 ? '00' : '30'}').reversed.toList();

        hours.forEach(print);
        print('Hours-------- $hours');
        return {
          'success': true,
          'hours': hours,
        };
      }
      return response;
}
```

[image]

the response i get is:

```
{"success":true,"working_hours":[{"day":"Monday","start_time":"09:00","end_time":"17:00","is_holiday":false}]}
```

This gives list of hours

```
[9:00, 9:30, 10:00, 10:30, 11:00, 11:30, 12:00, 12:30, 13:00, 13:30, 14:00, 14:30, 15:00, 15:30, 16:00, 16:30, 17:00, 17:30]
```

The end hour is 17:00. but its showing extra adding 17:30.
This happens every time when an hour is ending with __:00.

For example:
If response is

```
{"day":"Monday","start_time":"11:00","end_time":"15:00","is_holiday":false}
```

the hours will be:

```
[11:00, 11:30, 12:00, 12:30, 13:00, 13:30, 14:00, 14:30, 15:00, 15:30]
```

Comment: Quote exactly what is expected and what issue you are currently facing.

Comment: i want the hours should be split in 30 mins.. the starttime and end should be the same as the start_time and end_time from the response...

Comment: If my understanding is not wrong, if start time is 10:00 and end time is 15:00 then you need to split it like 10:00, 10:30, 11:00, 11:30, 12:00, 12:30, 13:00, 13:30, 14:00, 14:30, 15:00  correct ?

Comment: The start time is 9:00 and the end time is 17:00 from response..

Comment: but from the above code, you can see the start time 9:00 which is correct but the end time 17:30 which is incorrect..

Comment: this happens only when an end_time which ends with __:00..

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your logic to generate the list is not correct. You can try the following:

```
List<String> hours = List.generate(hoursLeft * 2 - 1, (i) => '${startTime + (i/2).floor()}:${i%2 == 0 ? '00' : '30'}').toList();
```

First you need to generate N records where `N = hoursLeft * 2 - 1`. The minus one is because otherwise  you will generate one more record which is 17:30 because `18 - 9 = 9` and you will generate `9 * 2 = 18` records but you need only 17 to reach 17:00. Also in your code you use `endTime(i/2)` which should throw an error since endTime is not a method and can't be executed that way.

Comment: Hi @snaksa, i tried the above code.. the response i get is {"start_time":"00:30","end_time":"07:30"} and output im getting is                    
[0:00, 0:30, 1:00, 1:30, 2:00, 2:30, 3:00, 3:30, 4:00, 4:30, 5:00, 5:30, 6:00, 6:30, 7:00] and thats not correct..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TimeOfDay class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TimeOfDay-class.html) from Flutter and [Duration API](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.1/dart-core/Duration-class.html) to achieve the expected  result. Here is the sample snippet.

**Logic of splitting slots**

```
Iterable<TimeOfDay> getTimeSlots(TimeOfDay startTime, TimeOfDay endTime, Duration interval) sync* {
  var hour = startTime.hour;
  var minute = startTime.minute;

  do {
    yield TimeOfDay(hour: hour, minute: minute);
    minute += interval.inMinutes;
    while (minute >= 60) {
      minute -= 60;
      hour++;
    }
  } while (hour < endTime.hour || (hour == endTime.hour && minute <= endTime.minute));
}
```

**Use them like below**

```
final startTime = TimeOfDay(hour: 9, minute: 0);
final endTime = TimeOfDay(hour: 22, minute: 0);
final interval = Duration(minutes: 30);

final times = getTimeSlots(startTime, endTime, interval)
      .toList();
print(times);
```

End result will be the array of slots in `TimeOfDay` format. You can format it either in the `getTimeSlots` method or after receiving the array.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
List<String> generateTimeIntervals(String startTime, String endTime) {
  final start = DateTime.parse("2022-02-22 $startTime");
  final end = DateTime.parse("2022-02-22 $endTime");
  final result = <String>[];
  while (start.isBefore(end)) {
    result.add(formatTime(start));
    start = start.add(Duration(minutes: 30));
  }
  return result;
}

String formatTime(DateTime time) {
  return "${time.hour.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${time.minute.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}";
}
```